# Python 3 IDLE (Shell) but only Python 2.7 installed on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-idle

i installed Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi and it has Python 3 IDLE to write code. What confuses me is, that if i execute "python" in the command of my Raspberry Pi, it says the Python version is 2.7?
Can someone help?

Comment: Try running `python3`. As far as I know, `python` usually defaults to Python 2 if you have it installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it won't cause you any issues, you can try running `python3`. If you have Python 2 and 3 installed, from my experience `python` usually runs Python 2, so I guess you'll have to be specific.

Comment: The problem is, that i run Python 3 on my computer and i wanna switch this code to my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @TimWenke You can try uninstalling Python 2, if you have Python 3 installed it *may* run Python 3?